# Grails not listed in STS extensions

Tags: eclipse, spring, grails, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I recently installed Spring tool suite Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE.  I am trying to setup my grails environment but it is not available in the extensions tab as suggested by https://grails.org/wiki/STS%20Integration.  I have installed grails 3.0.3 on my machine as well.  Can anyone point me to how I can get grails integrated with my version of spring?

Comment: i don't use grails 3 yet, so im not sure but i think you don't need the grails extension because grails 3 uses gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the newer versions of STS do not include this extension in their default list of extensions.  You can install it by following the instructions for installing Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) for Eclipse listed here: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovygrails-tool-suite-ggts-eclipse/help

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the New & Noteworthy documentation (and in several announcements before), the groovy and grails integration for Eclipse and STS is no longer supported: http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v370/NewAndNoteworthy.html

You can get the latest version of the tooling for Eclipse 4.4 from the Marketplace or you can download the final version of GGTS (3.6.4, based on Eclipse 4.4) from here: https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all

The only exception to this is the groovy-eclipse tooling, which we updated for Eclipse 4.5 and is still available for STS 3.7.0 from the extension dashboard.